# Pysimplegui help, I want to rerun my process over and over

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface

I'm still learning python and I am giving myself a project which I am iterating on. I create some random game selectors using CSV files or text files.  So I did some research and made a simple gui using pysimplegui and it works. However I want to rerun the script to select a new game with I hit the reload button and I'm just not finding the information I looking for. Maybe I am overthinking it, or underthinking it.

```
import random
import csv
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#select Random game from CSV file
with open("Retro Games Spreadsheet! - Games!.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    chosen_row = random.choice(list(reader))
f.close()

print(chosen_row)
#Create the layout 
layout = [[sg.Text(chosen_row)], sg.Button("Reload")], 

# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Select Random Game", layout)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or
    # reloads with the Reload button
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Reload":
        window[[sg.Text(chosen_row)]]
    window.Refresh()
window.close()
```

Comment: It is not necessary to create a new window, just update the `sg.Text` element by `window[key_of_text_element].update(new_chosen_row)` when event "Reload". The same thing to do if you have more elements to update. `window.refresh()` is not required for next step will be `window.read()` and it will refresh window.

Answer (score 0):

Just update all related elements in your layout.

```py
import random
import csv
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#select Random game from CSV file
with open("Retro Games Spreadsheet! - Games!.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)

chosen_row = random.choice(rows)
#f.close()  it will be auto-closed after with statement

print(chosen_row)
#Create the layout
layout = [[sg.Text(chosen_row, key="-ROW-")], sg.Button("Reload")],

# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Select Random Game", layout)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or
    # reloads with the Reload button
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Reload":
        chosen_row = random.choice(rows)
        window['-ROW-'].update(chosen_row)

window.close()
```